# How to output 'selected' checkbox labels within a matrix

Tags: craft3, matrix, checkboxes

Newbie here.

First Craft 3 CMS build and fumbling with logic of Matrix blocks.

I've created a relatively simple matrix field, and I can output plain text and dropdown options, but not sure how to do a multiple choice field like checkboxes within a matrix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the checkbox fields much the same way they would be used if they were added directly to the entry and not in the matrix field. Assuming you've got a basic matrix field structure (using [`if`/`else`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html#templating) or [`switch`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/switch.html)):

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.all() %}

    {% switch block.type %}

        {% case "text" %}

            {{ block.textField | markdown }}

        {% case "image" %}

            {{ block.image[0].getImg() }}

        {% case "checkboxes" %}

            // HELP!!!

        {% default %}

            <p>A font walks into a bar.</p>
            <p>The bartender says, “Hey, we don’t serve your type in here!”</p>

    {% endswitch %}

{% endfor %}
```

You could use the same examples that are in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/checkboxes-fields.html#templating-examples) and just switch `entry` for the name of your block variable (`block` in our case):

#### Loop through the checked checkboxes:

```
{% for option in block.checkboxFieldHandle %}
    Label: {{ option.label }}
    Value: {{ option }} or {{ option.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Loop through all of the available checkboxes:

```
{% for option in block.checkboxFieldHandle.options %}
    Label:   {{ option.label }}
    Value:   {{ option }} or {{ option.value }}
    Checked: {{ option.selected ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### See if any checkboxes are checked:

```
{% if block.checkboxFieldHandle|length %}
```

#### See if a particular checkbox is checked:

```
{% if block.checkboxFieldHandle.contains('optionValue') %}
```